# White Balance Drift off from Pi Camera

Tags: python, raspicam, opencv

I'm currently trying to develop image tracking using color in Python 3 and OpenCV. But i am facing problem in PiCamera. At the moment, i've done some method to fix white balance, shutter speed, and other stuff. But i can't get something fixed yet. i assume it was a white balance that drift. this is my setting:

```
resch=[(640,480),(320,240)]
res=resch[0]
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = res
camera.framerate = 32
camera.awb_mode='off'
camera.awb_gains=Fraction(8,5)
camera.exposure_mode='backlight'
camera.shutter_speed=31098
camera.brightness = 50
camera.ISO = 400
camera.meter_mode = 'spot'
camera.contrast= 0
camera.drc_strength= 'off'
```

but when a color change in front of camera, the whole picture is changing too like this example:

[image: normal image]

and this is the picture when the red band goes center
[image: slight red in overall image]

i've changed the metering mode to 'spot' dunno if that make a different but the effect seems more predictable in this mode. i already change it to all of it's available option but the white balance? is still drifted in one or other way.

Comment: You probably want to change exposure mode to "off", but you want to do that *after* setting ISO and then waiting a second or so for the gains to stabilise.

Comment: setting exposure mode to off after setting ISO then delay few seconds did not solve the problem

Comment: @aji did you find a solution to this? If so it would be helpful to others if you post the answer here.